# Counter clockwise flux integral

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

There's a function $\ \varphi :(0,+\infty) \to \Bbb R$ and another function $\ u:\Bbb R^{2} \to \Bbb R$ defined as $\ u(x,y):=\varphi(x^2+4y^2)$. For some $\ t>0$, let $\ E_{t} = \{{(x,y): x^2+4y^2=t}\}. $

Now trying to find the counter clockwise flux $\ {\unicode{x2233}}_{E_{t}} \nabla u \cdot \bar n ds$ of $\ \nabla u$ across $\ E_{t}$ and find all functions $\ \varphi$ so that this flux is independent of t.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe start by making a universal substitution $2y = z$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function
$$v(x,y):=x^2+4y^2\ .$$ The set $E_t:=\{(x,y)\>|\>v(x,y)=t\}$, $t>0$, is an ellipse bounding an elliptical domain $D_t$ of area ${\pi\over2} t$. Assume that ${\bf n}$ is the outward normal of $E_t$. Then by Gauss' divergence theorem we have
$$\int_{E_t}\nabla v\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}s=\int_{D_t}{\rm div}(\nabla v)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ .$$
Since ${\rm div}(\nabla v)=\Delta v=v_{xx}+v_{yy}\equiv10$
we obtain
$$\int_{E_t}\nabla v\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}s=10\>{\rm area}(D_t)=5\pi t\ .$$
Of course we can as well compute the flux integral directly. To this end we parametrize $E_t$ as
$$E_t:\quad\theta\mapsto\sqrt{t}\bigl(\cos\theta,{1\over2}\sin\theta\bigr)\qquad(0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi)\ .$$
We then have
$${\bf n}\>{\rm d}s=(y_\theta, -x_\theta)\>d\theta=\sqrt{t}\bigl({1\over2}\cos\theta, \sin\theta\bigr)\>d\theta\ .$$
On the other hand $\nabla v=(2x,8y)$, so that our flux integral becomes
$$\int_{E_t}\nabla v\cdot {\bf n}\>{\rm d}s= \int_0^{2\pi}(\sqrt{t})^2(2\cos\theta,4\sin\theta)\cdot\bigl({1\over2}\cos\theta, \sin\theta\bigr)\>d\theta=5\pi t\ ,$$
as before.

Now we are interested in some other function $u(x,y):=\phi\bigl(v(x,y)\bigr)$ with a $\phi$ yet to be determined. The chain rule gives
$$\nabla u(x,y)=\phi'\bigl(v(x,y)\bigr)\>\nabla v(x,y)\ ,$$
whereby $\phi'(t)$ is a scalar factor. Since $v(x,y)\equiv t$ on $E_t$ we therefore have
$$\int_{E_t}\nabla u\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}s=\phi'(t)\int_{E_t}\nabla v\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}s=5\pi\>t\>\phi'(t)\ .$$
The right hand side is independent of $t$ iff $\phi'(t)={C\over t}$ for some constant $C$, and this is equivalent with
$$\phi(t)=C\>\log t+ C'$$
with $C'$ constant as well.

Comment: (Not the original questioner here...nice answer though) As I derive it, flux is $$\int_\Omega {F(\vec x) \circ \hat n(\vec x)~{\rm d}\vec x}$$, although I believe that is only under an ideal parameterization of uniform unit density.  Do you know what the significance of adding the $\nabla$ to the equation is:  $$\int_\Omega {\color{red}\nabla ~ F(\vec x) \circ \hat n(\vec x)~{\rm d}\vec x}$$ ...?  Does the quantity have a name?

Comment: Oh, also doesn't that theorem go by the name Stoke's theorem, and Curl Theorem?  I get them pretty confused.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this problem without using the divergence theorem?

Comment: In two dimensions  Gauss' and Greens  theorems are pretty much the same. The difference is in the physical interpretation: Whether you consider the given field as a flow field (as the OP did), or as a force field. – You can avoid Gauss' theorem by computing $\int_{E_t}\ldots$ as a line integral, using an obvious parametrization of $E_t$. Note that ${\bf n}ds=(-y_\theta,x_\theta)d\theta$.

Comment: For the line integral method, the $\ \nabla u$ is a little confusing - what is the integral we're taking? Also, for the parameterization of $\ E_{t}$, would it be $\ r(t)= (\sqrt{t} \cos{t}, \frac{ \sqrt{t} }{2} \sin{t})?

Comment: That last part should read $\ r(t)=(\sqrt{t} \cos{t}, \frac{\sqrt{t}}{2} \sin{t})$?

Comment: Definitely No: The letter $t$ stands for the "size" of $E_t$, while we need an auxiliary parameter $\theta$ running from $0$ to $2\pi$ in order  to produce and deal with $E_t$ as a curve.

Comment: Oh right of course, so I have a parameterisation $\ r(\theta) = (\sqrt{t} \cos{\theta}, \frac{\sqrt{t}}{2} \sin{\theta})$. Then we have a function $\ v(x,y)=(x^{2}+4y^{2})$, for which we calculate $\ \nabla v = (2x,8y)$ Then I find $\ \nabla v(r(\theta)) \cdot (-\frac{\sqrt{t}}{2} \sin{\theta}, \sqrt{t} \cos{\theta})$. At this point I took the integral between $\ 0$ and $\ 2\pi$ which came out with 0. I'm not sure if I'm on completely the wrong track or what here.

Comment: @IanBaker The parameterization $x = \sqrt t \cos(\theta), ~ y=\frac 12 \sqrt t \sin (\theta)$ will give you an incorrect answer by itself, because it does not equally weight each interval of the elliptical path, it equally weights angles instead.  You would need a weighting factor (that depends on $\theta$) to account for that.

Comment: Could you give an example? I don't quite follow

Comment: @DanielV: You are in error with your last comment. The $\theta$ is just "time", it is not the polar angle of the moving point. See my edit.